# Identify a netty client. Differences between ctx.Write(obj) and ctx.channel().Write(obj)

Tags: netty, channel, handshake

I want to know if it is the same (calling them in MyHandler.messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, object msg)).

If it is the same, could I do the following:

1)Add a Channel to a hashmap

```
@Override
protected void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf msg) throws Exception {
    //In this handler we add the client to a hashmap
    short id = msg.readShort();
    AllClients.addClient(id, ctx.channel());
}
```

2)In other handler of another Client, send a message to the last client:

```
protected void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Message msg) throws Exception {
    //In this handler we send a message to other client
    short id = msg.readShort();
    AllClients.getClient(id)
            .getChannel()
            .WriteAndFlush(id + "->" + Message.readString());
}
```

Sorry if I express myself bad, I am not English. Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that ctx.write(...) will start the write on the context that means only the ChannelOutboundHandler in front of it will see the write while channel.write(...) will begin at the tail of the ChannelPipeline and so all ChannelOutboundHandler will see the write. You want most likely use the former.

Comment: Well, in my case I am interested in using channel.write(..).
Thanks for the answer, it is clear and precise :)